# Refactor code so that top entity behaves like a context

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, orm

Consider the following two entities

```
           1    n
Department -----> Student
```

Suppose that there is a ton of legacy code based on this structure.

Now suppose that a new entiy, `Univeristy` has to be introduced:

```
           1     n            1    n
Univeristy ------> Department -----> Student
```

`University`, however, must behave like a **context** not just like an ordinary entity, in the following way.
Whenever a user of the system authenticates himself as belonging to Univeristy X, and calls one of the legacy methods, access must be granted to only those entities which belong (directly or indirectly) to University X. The context lives till the user logs off. (This is a web application.)

So, for example a line like

`dbContext.Set<Student>()`

somewhere in the legacy code should return only those students who belong to University X.

What options do I have? Modifying the legacy code is not an option.

Comment: This would be more clear if you could give an example of legacy code that should remain the same but still behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to give you a precise answer without knowing how the legacy code fits in to the picture but I'll give it a shot.

Depending on how your database is set up (for example, if there is a University Id on the Student database table) you may be able to just add a Students navigation property.

```
public class University
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

If that doesnt work, you might try to access all the Students through the Departments:

```
public class University
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students 
    {
        get { return Departments.SelectMany(d => d.Students); }
    }
}
```

That may be less efficient however.

Finally, you could use the repository pattern and create a StudentRepository which would allow you to run a variety of queries to get Students.

```
public class StudentRepository
{
      public IEnumerable<Student>  GetStudents(University university) 
      {
           return dbContext.Set<Student>().Where(s => s.Department.University.Id == university.Id);
      }
}
```

Another suggestion I would make is to not have a DbContext last for the entire time that the User is logged in.  I would create a DbContext for each web request.  Search for Entity Framework Unit of Work to see what I mean.